# Testing babel-preset-env using package.json

Tags: babel-preset-env

Noob question here. Trying to assure myself that `babel-preset-env` works.

I install `babel-core` and `babel-preset-env`:

```
yarn add --dev babel-core
yarn add --dev babel-preset-env
```

My `package.json` has:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "IE >= 8"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
},
```

I create a JS script to test:

```
fs.readFile('my.js', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  let babel = require("babel-core");
  let result = babel.transform(data).code;
});
```

I test with arrow functions in `my.js`:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('whatever');
});
```

No matter how I tweak `targets.browsers`, the arrow function does not get converted.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this with `babel-cli`. Works.

It's clear that `babel-core` (the Javascript API of Babel) does not pick up anything from `package.json`.

Filed an issue here too: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7647

The [JS API docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/) probably needs to be updated.

In order to use `babel-preset-env` in JS API:

```js
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const ug = require('uglify-es');
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
execFile('npx', ['babel', 'my.js'], (err, data, stderr) => {
  if (err) throw err; // U get the idea

  let result = ug.minify(data, { mangle: { toplevel: true } }).code;
});
```